# Reading a novel in .doc format

Tags: word

I want to read a novel in Word (.doc) format on my Nokia Lumia 525. The problem is that I am not able to bookmark any pages, and it is very difficult to scroll to the page where I left off and unfortunately my novel does not have any index page at the start.

How can I make reading books in Word more convenient?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware that Word on Windows Phone can do what you want.

On your PC you can convert the document to PDF (via [PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com/) or another free PDF converter) or ePub via [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) (also free, but offhand while I know it'll convert Word documents, I've never done it and don't know how well). Upload it to OneDrive.

You can use an ePub reader from the Marketplace (such as [Nokia Reading](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/nokia-reading/ab0d89cb-73a4-4ff8-93dd-91bec9f855bd)) to open from OneDrive.

Comment: Modern versions of MS Office can also save to PDF, as can [Word Online](https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help but am looking for some way that I would be able to read novel without index in my nokia lumia 525

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if word on WP has reading mode or not but MS Word on Windows has a reading mode that will automatically reflow text in the file to make it easier to read. You can also convert the file to pdf and choose some pdf readers that support text reflow option.

Comment: can I know the reason for the downvote?